# How to make date picker parse unix timestamp

Tags: angular-material, mat-datepicker

I'm trying to pass in a unix timestamp to mat date-picker. But, it's not getting parsed.

This is the custom date format i'm passing to MAT_DATE_FORMATS

```
export const DATE_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'X',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS],
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DATE_FORMATS },
]
```

How to support parsing of unix timestamp with date picker?